# How can you change the value of a string pointer that is passed to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdstring

I need to change the value of a std::string using a function.

The function must be void, and the parameter must be a pointer to a string as shown.

```
#include <iostream>

void changeToBanana(std::string *s) {
    std::string strGet = "banana";
    std::string strVal = strGet;
    s = &strVal;
}

    int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    std::string strInit = "apple";
    std::string* strPtr;
    strPtr = &strInit;
        changeToBanana(strPtr);
        std::cout << *strPtr << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I would like the resulting print to say "banana"
Other answers involve changing parameter.

I have tried assigning the string using a for loop, and going element by element, but that did not work. The value remained the same.

Comment: Try `*s = strVal;`

Comment: *"I would like the resulting print to say 'banana'"* -- looks simple enough. Why make things so complicated for yourself by introducing more variables than you need? You want `*s` to become "banana", so set it equal to that.

Comment: any reason to not use references? this example doesn't scream `pointer` at me

Comment: the pointer is passed by value. Any changes you make to `s` in the function do not affect the pointer in `main`. You can however modify the string it points to

Comment: It depends on what you are actually trying to do. If you want the string currently pointed to by `strPtr` to now contain `"banana"` then you are just missing an indirection (`*s = strCal;`). If you want `strPtr` to point to a different string which already contains `"banana"` then that becomes much more complicated and a raw pointer is a poor tool for that job.

Comment: I dont agree with the duplicate. OP is requiring to not change the signature which means its not possible to access a variable out of scope. The right fix would be to use a reference as argument and then the dupe is not that relevant

Comment: woah I didnt mean to reopen singlehandedly, just wanted to vote and forgot about my powers ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number apparently I was the other hand

Comment: I was on the same path as the duplicate because of: `s = &strVal;`  but then realized the variable `s` was passed by value making the `s = &strVal;` do nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function must be void, and the parameter must be a pointer to a string as shown.

With this requirements you cannot change the value of the pointer that is passed to the function, because it is passed by value.

Don't confuse the pointer with what it points to. Parameters are passed by value (unless you pass them by reference). A copy is made and any changes you make to `s` in the function do not apply to the pointer in `main`.

However, you can change the string pointed to by the pointer (because `s` points to the same string as the pointer in `main`):

```
void changeToBanana(std::string *s) {
    std::string str = "banana";
    *s = str;
}
```

However, this is not idiomatic C++. You should rather pass a a reference `void changeToBanana(std::string& s)` or return the string `std::string returnBanana()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void changeToBanana(std::string *s) {
    std::string strGet = "banana";
    std::string strVal = strGet;
    
    // the following line doesn't do anything
    //  useful, explanation below
    s = &strVal;
}
```

`s = &strVal` assigns the address of the `strVal` to `s`. Then the function ends and any modifications made to `s` are "forgotton", becase `s` is a *local* variable of `changeToBanana`.

So calling `changeToBanana(&foo)` does nothing.

You either want this:

```
void changeToBanana(std::string *s) {
    *s = "banana";
}
...
std::string strInit = "apple";
changeToBanana(&strInit);
```

or this (preferred because you don't need pointers):

```
void changeToBanana(std::string & s) {
    s = "banana";
}
...
std::string strInit = "apple";
changeToBanana(strInit);
```